# Объясните, пожалуйста, постановку двоеточия!

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис, двоеточие, бсп

> А я ехала сейчас, говорила с вами и всё думала: почему они не стреляют?

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему в этом предложении употреблено двоеточие, а не запятая? У Розенталя сказано, что это БСП, тогда каким членом в нем является слово «почему»? Можно ли в этом предложении поставить запятую, то есть сделать его СПП, и если да, что изменится? Правильно ли я понимаю, что оно БСП только из-за предупредительной интонации?

Comment: Пожалуйста, объясните постановку минуса.  Автор вопроса стремится разобраться, в чем смыл оформления одной и той же фразы по образцу СПП и БСП, то есть его интересует сравнительный анализ двух конструкций. Я при ответе добавила еще третий вариант.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Рассмотрим три варианта оформления подобных предложений.

1. *А я ехала сейчас, говорила с вами и всё думала: **почему они не стреляют**?*

У Розенталя есть правило (п.5) : . Перед **прямым вопросом**, включенным в состав бессоюзного сложного предложения, ставится двоеточие:  *Одного только я не понимаю: **как она могла тебя укусить**?* (Ч.); http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=150#pp150

Такое БСП по структуре и интонации очень похоже на прямую речь, сравнить: *Тогда он спросил: «*Как же она могла тебя укусить*?».*

Двоеточием обозначена **предупредительная пауза**, тон понижается, а далее следует сам вопрос,  причем **вопросительную интонацию** мы обозначаем знаком вопроса и повышением голоса во второй части предложения.

Таким образом, в  таком  БСП мы можем выделить вопрос, оформить его в самостоятельную часть.  Местоимение ПОЧЕМУ здесь является **вопросительным словом** (вопросительным обстоятельством),  как и в простом предложении.

2. Если мы не хотим этого делать, то можно предложение оформить **как СПП с косвенным вопросом:**

*А я Ехала сейчас, говорИла с вами и всё дУмала,  почему они не стрелЯют.*

Местоимение ПОЧЕМУ стало союзным словом,  предупредительной паузы нет, вопросительной интонации  (повышения тона) тоже нет.

3. В то же время Розенталь разрешает **выделить вопрос и в СПП тоже** (паузы нет, но есть знак вопроса и вопросительная интонация).
   Розенталь (п.4)   http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=88#pp88

Примечание. Если придаточная часть сложноподчиненного предложения содержит **косвенный вопрос**, то в конце предложения вопросительный знак обычно не ставится: *Я прервал речь Савельича вопросом, **сколько** у меня всего денег* (П.); *Корчагин неоднократно спрашивал меня, **когда** он может выписаться* (Н. О.).

Однако, если косвенный вопрос содержит **сильно выраженную вопросительную интонацию**, в конце сложноподчиненного предложения ставится вопросительный знак: Скажите, пожалуйста, **что это за огни?** (Л. Т.); *Я спросил, **как же он стал отшельником**?* (М. Г.)

Вывод:

Вопрос: Правильно ли я понимаю, что оно БСП только из-за предупредительной интонации?

Ответ: Не только из-за предупредительной интонации.

У нас есть **три варианта оформления:**

1. БСП: предупредительная и  вопросительная интонация.
2. СПП без знака вопроса: нет предупредительной и вопросительной интонации.
3. СПП со знаком вопроса: нет предупредительной интонации, но есть вопросительная интонация.

Comment: Вам огромное спасибо! Если подытожить: СПП без вопросительной интонации стало БСП вследствие наличия предупредительной интонации в первой части и вопросительной во второй, я правильно понял? Если такое предложение, к примеру, дано без знаков препинания, то постановка знака препинания на стыке частей факультативна? Предпосылки в тексте к выбору той или иной синтаксической конструкции нет?

Comment: Да, всё правильно. С другой стороны, факультативное авторское решение  тоже должно быть обоснованным, например,  структурой предложения, опорными глаголами речи, контекстом. В приведенном предложении удобно именно двоеточие,  так как оно делится на две части. В первой части перечислительная интонация однородных членов, эту часть лучше как-то обособить, а вопрос выделить отдельно.  Запятую же удобно ставить в нераспространенных предложениях. Ну и контекст важен, предложение должно вписываться в текст интонационно. Формально все три варианта возможны, но разные факторы при выборе надо учитывать.