# Это БСП или СПП?

Tags: грамматика, спп, бсп

**[У Розенталя, пункт 5](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=88):**

*А я ехала сейчас, говорила с вами и всё думала: **почему они не стреляют?*** (Сим.).

Там сказано, что это **БСП.** Но ведь ***"почему"*** может быть **союзным словом,** и тогда можно считать, что **СПП.**  Двоеточие в СПП является **неосновным** знаком.

Так **какое** же это предложение?

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461484/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%8a%d1%8f%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%83%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%8f

Comment: Спасибо, Серж. Я не нашла эту тему, хотя помнила о ней.

Answer (score 1):

Я задала свой вопрос в соответствии с **[недавней темой](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/476592/%D0%A3-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8)** на форуме:

*У меня был только **один вопрос: что** он там такого сделал-таки?*

Обсуждался вопрос о постановке **вопросительного знака**, но при этом грамматика не была названа, хотя предполагалось, что это **СПП**. Я же думаю, что это все-таки **БСП** (раскрытие содержания местоимения "*одного*").

Что касается **[повтора темы](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461484/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%8F),** то объяснение вариантов (БСП или СПП) было дано, но это **частное суждение**. Хотелось бы увидеть, как решается этот вопрос **в лингвистике,** ведь это касается **грамматики**.

И еще желательно определиться **с однозначным выбором**: по каким признакам он делается. Это может быть **контекст** или какие-то **структурные элементы** в самом предложении.

Я не считаю, что эта тема **полностью** раскрыта.

Comment: СПП назвать этот пример сложно. Здесь БСП. У Розенталя все ясно написано

Comment: Розенталь – это не справочник по грамматике.  Определите вид предложения без Розенталя.  Как вы это сделаете?

Comment: Розенталь  как-раз объясняет.Обычно различается пунктуация в бессоюзном сложном предложении, в котором вторая часть раскрывает содержание местоименного слова одно, имеющегося в первой части (ставится двоеточие), и в простом предложении, в котором слово одно разъясняется пояснительным членом предложения, а не целым предложением (ставится тире). Ср.: Я вам скажу только одно: нельзя сидеть сложа руки (Ч.); В отношениях с посторонними он требовал одного — сохранения приличия (Герц.).